# Will interrupting model training cell, and re-fitting with new callbacks, reinitialise the model weights?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm training a CNN on google colab pro, and unfortunately thought about adding the ModelCheckpoint callback too late. Despite being on google pro, the model very simple model has been training for 10 hours now.

If I interrupt the model.fit cell (I stop it running), and add the ModelCheckpoint callback to the callbacks in the model.fit function, will the model re-train from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

**Brief answer**: No.

**A longer answer**: You can actually try the following: take your model and look at the initial loss for example

[image]

As you can see, at the end of the first epoch the training loss is 0.2499. Now I modify the parameters in the fit method adding a callback.

[image]

And at the beginning of the first epoch, we have the training starting with lower loss.

In order to restart the training you have to recompile the model.